# Polygamy and ways of the nations

Tags: polygamy

Would **not** practicing Polygamy fall under the category of copying the customs of gentiles? A certain mainstream religion makes a point of having one and only one wife.
Are Jews technically copying that gentile custom, by practicing monogamy?

Comment: Doesn't Jewish monogamy predate non Jewish monogamy?

Comment: @robev Can you give us a source for your statement? If anything, polygamy was all over the place in Sefer Bereishith.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Jewish monogamy was inspired by gentiles and not something we decided to do on our own for our own reasons?

Comment: @DoubleAA No I don't have any evidence.  But, I do know that if there is a custom that gentiles have, then we stay far away from it. For example, In 200 B.C.E, there would have been nothing inherently wrong with have a pine tree during the month of December in your living room, but that definitely would be an issue these days. Yes, we can have such a tree in our living rooms for our own reasons, but it still would create the appearance of copying gentiles.

Comment: @FawazAlLawz Many gentiles shower daily. In 200 BCE that would have been unheard of.

Comment: @DoubleAA Showering for gentiles has no religious basis; for this particular religion that I mentioned ( Not that I am aware of  ). On the other hand, being monogamous does have a religious basis for them.

Comment: @DoubleAA If you pick 25 normal, educated joes off the street in the western world and ask them to name 10 similarities between Judaism and that other major Western religion; I am pretty sure monogamy will be on that list.

Comment: Monogamy was likely instituted to avoid persecution from notzrim but not to copy them

Comment: @FawazAlLawz "If anything, polygamy was all over the place in Sefer Bereishith." Not so. Some wicked people had multiple wives, and some good people (Avraham, Yaakov) ended up _stuck_ with multiple wives due to circumstances beyond their control. Some kings later had multiple wives for political reasons, part of their jobs so to speak. In general, it is very hard to find any examples of sages in the Mishnah or Talmud who had more than one wife. See Yalkut Shmuel 77 (www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.77.3): "Two wives? The verse ... mentions his shame..."

Comment: Having two wives was generally not *recommended* for normal situations, even though it was *allowed*. Having one wife was never something to raise eyebrows at.

Comment: @Esther I think I agree but do you have a source for that? There are strong arguments from good sources that in certain earlier times, a woman without a husband was in a very grave situation, and there weren't enough men to go around etc.

Comment: Can there be an issue in going in the ways of the goyim by not doing something? Wouldn’t the issue only be in the affirmative such as having a tree? Doing something like them appears as though you are trying to behave like them. Not doing something gives no appearance. Perhaps you are married to one individual because that’s your preference or all you could afford?

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance through the Tanach would show that for the most part, monogamy was the norm. While polygamy was not considered immoral, it was still not regularly practiced.

In fact, whenever you come across one of the biblical heroes marrying a second wife, it is always with a special reason and with the wife permission. This is besides for the case of Jacob, which was a trick to begin with.

To see the attitude of the Torah you can see how God spoke to Noah in [Genesis 7:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he), where he refers to animal couples as 'a man and his wife'.

This continues into the Talmud as well. There is no Talmudic sage, who comes to mind, who had two wives at once. On the contrary, the word for a co-wife is צרה, which [is explained](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.18.18.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) as literally being a pain. And so, it is obvious that it was never considered a very positive type of relationship.

Comment: True, but I think kings, even the righteous ones, need a carve-out. It seems like it was part of the job to marry a lot of wives.

Comment: @MichoelR That's true.

Answer (score 1):

I like where you are going with this.

But, generally the prohibition against copying the customs of the gentiles does not apply to something that has a rational basis. See Rama Yoreh Deah 178:1: וכל זה אינו אסור אלא בדבר שנהגו בו העובדי כוכבים לשם פריצות . . .  או בדבר שנהגו למנהג ולחוק ואין טעם בדבר דאיכא למיחש ביה משום דרכי האמורי ושיש בו שמץ עבודת כוכבים מאבותיהם **אבל דבר שנהגו לתועלת . . . מותר**

This is of course assuming there's a rational basis for monogamy :)